# How to read parquet file partitioned by date folder to dataframe from s3 using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyarrow, fastparquet

Using python, I should go till cwp folder and get into the date folder and read the parquet file.
I have this folder structure inside s3.

**Sample s3 path:**

**bucket name = lla.analytics.dev**

**path = bigdata/dna/fixed/cwp/dt=YYYY-MM-DD/file.parquet**

```
s3://lla.analytics.dev/bigdata/dna/fixed/cwp/dt=2021-11-24/file.parquet
                                             dt=2021-11-25/file.parquet
                                             dt=2021-11-26/file.parquet
                                             ........................
                                             ........................
                                             dt=YYYY-MM-DD/file.parquet
```

I should access the recent date folder and read the files into dataframe from s3

Comment: What's your version of pandas? (`pd.__version__`)

Comment: it is version 1.3.4 @user17242583

Comment: Try adding these two lines before the call to `fp_obj.to_pandas()`: `import pandas` and `print(pandas.__version__)`

Comment: Add it before the `df = fp_obj.to_pandas()` line.

Answer (score 2):

I see you have pyarrow tagged.  If you would like to use pyarrow (disclaimer, I work with pyarrow), you should be able to do:

```
import pyarrow.fs as fs
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

s3, path = fs.FileSystem.from_uri("s3://lla.analytics.dev/bigdata/dna/fixed/cwp")
dataset = ds.dataset(path, partitioning='hive', filesystem=s3, format='parquet')
table = dataset.to_table()
```

There are a lot more details in pyarrow's [filesystem docs](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/filesystems.html) and [tabular dataset](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/dataset.html) docs.  There are also recipes for this on the [pyarrow cookbook](https://arrow.apache.org/cookbook/py/io.html#reading-partitioned-data-from-s3).

Comment: I'm getting this error:  When getting information for key 'Bigdata/DNA/fixed/cwp' in bucket 'lla.analytics.dev': AWS Error [code 15]: No response body.

Comment: Dataset line getting some error..above code is not working...

Comment: My best guess would be a permissions issue or a region issue.  By default that code will use your region and secret key from the same configuration files the [AWS CLI uses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html).  Are you able to list the files in that bucket using the AWS CLI?

Comment: "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pyarrow._dataset'",

Comment: I'm trying to execute the above code in Lambda but getting this error

Comment: That error would suggest that pyarrow is not properly installed on the lambda image.  It's difficult to say what could be the cause without knowing a lot more about how the image is created.

Comment: Any other approach of reading parquet file to dataframe with date partitioned from s3?

Comment: I should access the recent date folder from s3 and read the parquet files into dataframe. Is there any approach to do this better?

Comment: There are a number of tools out there that can read partitioned parquet data but I'm not familiar with all of them and couldn't begin to say which is the best.